# Populate text field from JsTree selection

Tags: javascript, html, jstree

I am trying to figure out a way to pass the selection from JSTree to a basic HTML form.  (Which is then used by Flask & Wtforms).  I've been able to pass it to the console log but then am not sure how to bring this back to the form.

Relatively new to JS so take it easy on me, but I am stumped on how to do this.

```
<label for="folderpath">Folder Path:</label>
<input type="text"  id="folderpath" name="folderpath" value="">
<br>
<div id="container"></div>

<script id="jstree1" name="jstree1">

    $('#container').jstree({

    'core': {
        "themes": {
                "name": "default",
                "dots": true,
                "icons": true

            },        
        'data': {
                    'url': "static/JSONData.json",
                    'type': 'GET',
                    'dataType': 'JSON',
                }
                }
            });var folderpath =
        $('#container').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      console.log(data.instance.get_selected(true)[0].text);
});
 </script>
```

EDIT
I tried using #folderout.  But it would not work when using an input type="text" tag.

```
   <label for="folderout">Folder Path</label>
   <input type="text" name="folderout" class="form-control" id="folderout" >

       $("#container").on("select_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
       var number = data.node.text
       $('#folderout').html(number);
```

Comment: Try this,$('#container').on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      callback(data.instance.get_selected(true));
}); 'changed.jstree' is the event name, and the function is the script to be executed in case that event is fired, hence you need to call the callback in your function with parameter 'data.instance.get_selected(true)', returning all the currently selected items

Comment: Thanks AbhilashK, but I would need to pass the clicked value to an HTML input type text.  How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please see my edit.  I tried doing this with a "folderout" tag but it would not populate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <label for="folderout">Folder Path</label>
 <input type="text" name="folderout" class="form-control" id="folderout" >

<script id="jstree1" name="jstree1">

                                $('#container').jstree({
                                    'core': {
                                        "themes": {
                                            "name": "default"
                                            , "dots": true
                                            , "icons": true
                                        }
                                        , 'data': {
                                            'url': "static/JSONData.json"
                                            , 'type': 'GET'
                                            , 'dataType': 'JSON'
                                        }
                                    }
                            });
{ /*  --- THIS IS FOLDER SELECTOR FOR ID "folderout" --- */
$("#container").on("select_node.jstree", function (evt, data) {
var number = data.node.text
document.getElementById("folderout").value = number;  });};
</script>
```

The last part here did the trick.  Converting the data.node.text to a variable.  Then bringing the variable into html with getElementById.  Now when you click a node it will populate that text field.

Comment: Why the code (edit added) did not work earlier because you used html on input. Input tags (and selects) require value to be used like, $('#folderout').val(number). For other tags (like p, div, span, etc) require text through html.